# Limit for open files

Tags: lsof

I have a java application that is failing with

```
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:477) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:287) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [na:1.8.0-internal]
```

my limit for open files is 30K

```
$ ulimit -a
...
open files                      (-n) 30480
...
```

I'm wondering now, what is the proper check...

`lsof | grep 123 | wc -l` (123 is pid of java application) returns number 45633.

How it could be over 30K?

On the other hand `lsof -p 123| wc -l` returns only 771 - it's not over the limit.

Can someone help me to understand what's going on here? What am I missing? Is the limit sum for all user processes (that's what I'd expect)?

This is RedHat 7, Lsof revision 4.87.

**edit:** ok, I believe I know what is the discrepancy - `lsof -p ...` shows open files for parent only while there are subprocesses

Thanks to a comment from @schily I found that limit per subprocess is 4K only (and not 30K).

Comment: If you were on a system with `procfs` support, you could use the command `pfiles` with the process ID of the failing process as argument to get the related `rlimit`, but it seems that you are on Linux.

Comment: `pfiles`/`rlimit` not available for me...

Comment: `rlimit` is not a command but a UNIX feature since 1979. `pfiles` needs `procfs` and since you are on Linux, you only have something that is remotely similar to `procfs` from it's inventor Roger Faulkner. But I just discovered that Linux has `/proc/<pid>/limits`.

Comment: Thank you very much - `/proc/<pid>/limits` helped, I can see there 4K max, I was not able so far to find (google it) how to increase it for subprocess... Seems the limits are not applied somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case, as I'm running it as a service (I didn't mention as I didn't know it's important), was to add

```
LimitNOFILE=8192
```

to my service file under `/etc/systemd`

That service file specifies, that it has to be run as some specific user, but still the limits were not used for this user.